# Google Web App not opening http link when using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

There is probably a much better solution than the one I came up with below but it solved my initial problem of trying to pass variables from a google apps script to javascript within a Google Web App. The scriptlets in a web page make a large number of script calls and because it does so synchronously the page looks like it isn't loading for a good 15 seconds. Javascript solved this problem.

```
function doGet(e) {
  //check to see what the user is hoping to do
  var upTo = e.parameter.upTo;
  var userAgentResponse = HtmlService.getUserAgent();
  //check where we are up to, URL will need ?upTo=profile added to it.
  if (upTo == "profile"){
    //get name from URL will need ?upTo=profile&firstName=placeholder&surname=placeholder
    var firstName = e.parameter.firstName;
    var surname = e.parameter.surname;
    var fullName = firstName + " " + surname;
    if (userAgentResponse.indexOf("iPhone")>-1) { //check to see if it is an iPhone and then use the specific iPhone profile page becaause of viewport issues
      //var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('iphoneProfilePage');
      var code = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('iphoneProfilePage').getContent();
    }//end if Iphone
    else {
      //var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('profilePage');
      var code = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('profilePage').getContent();
    }//end else
    //t.data = [firstName, surname, userAgentResponse]; 
    //return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setTitle("Response Services Inc.").addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0');
    var newCode = code.replace("<script id=\"firstLoad\">", "<script id=\"firstLoad\">\n var firstName = \"" + firstName + "\";\n var surname = \"" + surname + "\";\n" +
                        "var fullName = \"" + fullName + "\";\n");
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(newCode).asTemplate();
    return html.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setTitle("Response Services Inc.").addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
  }
}
```

The next snag I hit has baffled me and others that I have spoken to. In the HTML below there are a couple of http links and a number of https links. It appears that the http links run foul of the https protocol when using my doGet() above and doesn't open the new page, but when I use the commented out code (that is, createTemplateFromFile(), instead of createHtmlOutput().asTemplate()) the http links work fine. Also, if I have the link open in a new window then the page opens fine. A new window is not a good solution as users need to navigate backwards and forwards.

```
 <nav>
  <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="http://rsi-intranet.org" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://script.google.com/a/macros/responseservices.org/s/AKfycbyz6TzObVUrWo0fiXHH0vU9DNO3511w1tVWrdVEUVsrjo_ejVHS/exec?upTo=SUList&letter=0">Service Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://script.google.com/a/macros/responseservices.org/s/AKfycbyyVpvvDivBcwktFmHw-DrxWOTKUT17Ir2jdG2Oi4c/exec?upTo=progDays">Activities & Supports</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.rsi-intranet.org/policies-and-procedures" target="_blank">Policies and Procedures</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.rsi-intranet.org/quick-forms" target="_blank">Quick Forms</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.rsi-intranet.org/help-and-learning" target="_blank">Help & Learning</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I've searched the Google Apps documentation regarding this but haven't come across a reason as yet. Would love to know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use target="_blank" with your hyperlinks because the web app is served inside an IFRAME. Some websites may deny links inside IFRAME by setting the X-Frame-Options header as DENY.